# What gets shown in *Messages* when I run pushd in shell, and how to modify it?

Tags: shell-mode

I use inferior shells (initiated with `M-x shell`) extensively.

If the current buffer is one such inferior shell, and within this shell I invoke the `pushd` command (with or without an argument), a space-separated list of directories gets written to `*Messages*`.  For example, what gets printed to the `*Messages*` buffer may look something like this

```
/some/path /some/other/path /yet/another/path ~/and/guess/what/one/more/path
```

This looks very much like a directory stack.

I find, however, that this directory-stack-like message is very often *quite different* from the output I actually get if I run `dirs` in the inferior shell.

**Q1:** how does Emacs figure out what to print to `*Messages*` when I invoke the `pushd` command in an inferior shell?

**Q2:** how can I reset Emacs' state so that what gets printed to `*Messages*` when I invoke the `pushd` command in an inferior shell is consistent with the output from running `dirs` in that shell?

One thing I can say is that running the Emacs command `M-x dirs` is not a suitable answer to Q2, primarily because, more often than not, when I run `M-x dirs`, Emacs just hangs, until I hit `C-g`.

Comment: Function `shell-dirstack-message` handles printing to `*Messages*`. What differences are you seeing between that and `dirs` in the shell?

Comment: @Mark: the output in `*Messages*` usually has more entries (often many more) than what the shell's `dirs` shows.

Comment: @Mark: thank you for the pointer to `shell-dirstack-message`.  From looking at its source code, I see that the output that it prints is derived, for the most part, from the value of the `shell-dirstack` variable.  This is basically the answer I was looking for.